# Change method to return a JSON string array of arrays

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to change the below method to return a JSON string array of arrays each with two elements (I.E. [value, date]). Currently I have a method that builds out the JSON string as one large single array of objects, how could I change it to the desired format instead? 
Currently the returned JSON from this method looks like this

```
{[{"measurementshortdate": "9/27","value": 99.99,}, {"measurementshortdate": "9/27","value": 104.57,}, {"measurementshortdate": "9/28","value": 232.21,}]}
```

This is the method I'm using to build it out.

```
    public string GetJSONAbbottSeriesData()
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("[");

        foreach (MeasurementGroup m in this.MeasurementTypeGroups[0].MeasurementGroups)
        {
            if (sb.ToString() != "[")
            {
                sb.Append(", ");
            }

            sb.Append("{" +
                "\"measurementshortdate\": \"" + m.When.ToString("M/dd") + "\"," +
                "\"value\": " + m.Measurements[0].Value.ToString("0.##") + "," +
                "}");
        }

        sb.Append("]");

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Actually now that I'm thinking about it, this may not even be possible.

Comment: Try to use Json Serializer to transform an object into JSON format. It will be easier!

Comment: Do you have an example of this. Basically I just need to get a string like this returned '[12/4, 5.4], [10/2, 2], [9/12, 3], [9/19, 2]'

Comment: Check this [link](http://matijabozicevic.com/blog/csharp-net-development/csharp-serialize-object-to-json-format-using-javascriptserialization) for basic javascriptserialization example

Comment: Or just search Json.Net, you'll find plenty of answers

Comment: `12/4` is not valid JSON.

Answer (score -1):

You need to make sure that you are making the right format, for example...

```
{"page":1,"total":1,"records":"2","rows":[
  {"group":[{ label: 'child1' }, { label: 'child2' }],
   "group":[{ label: 'child1' }, { label: 'child2' }],
   "group":[{ label: 'child1' }, { label: 'child2' }]]}
```

The format above have some features before the data because is used in JQgrid, I had to change my JSon format because I was using Entity Framework and he don't return the correct format.

So you just need to manipulate your string to return data as you wish, review your sb.Append command in debug mode and see if the return is in correct format.